# provision sharepoint page using visual studio Module

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, module

I need to provision SharePoint page using Visual Studio module, and the following is the module file:

[image]

The page deployed successfully and I can open it, but if I edit the page properties and navigate back to the page, the following error appears:

[image]

Comment: Is line 32 actually present in the file you're deploying?

Comment: no, SharePoint generate it after publish the page

Comment: Your module XML looks fine. I'd guess there's a corruption in your page markup. If you deploy a generic page - like a copy of an OOB file - in this manner does the error still occur?

Comment: @DerekGusoff yes, thank you, it solved, the issue was with "asp:content" I changed it to "asp:Content"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replace "asp:content" with "asp:Content"